# Before_action causing too many redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm wondering what would be the best way to handle the following:

I have an authentication method (used as a before_action) as follows that checks if a user_id is in the session when the login page is requested. If the user_id is detected, then it redirects the user to dashboard path.

```
def already_validated
    if session[:uid] == user.id
        redirect_to dash_path
    end
end
```

This is leading to a too many redirect errors which I understand. I can see in pry that it's just evaluating that before_action filter every-time the page loads. That's what leads to too many redirects.

My question is what is the best way to handle this type of setup. Is there a way in rails to only evaluate on the first redirect? I thought of using a temp flag to tell if the redirect happened before. That doesn't seem very elegant though. I'm sure there is an easier/better way to manage it.

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Have you had a look yet at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise ? It may be easier than trying to hand spin authentication if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: No thanks, I more so want to understand what's happening here for future reference. I did come across throw(:abort) but that doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: In your code, if a user is already validated (and so the session has *:uid*), then it asks the user to sign in? Why? That doesn't make sense…  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be an exception on your `before_action`: you don't want to call it on the `dash_path`. If a user enters there and is validated, it should stay there (as what the `redirect` would do) and if it is not validated it should just stay there (as with any other url that fails this validation process).

There is no point on checking if it is validated as the result will always be to stay on the same page.

Then in your controller you have to specify that you want an exception on the `before_action`:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action: :already_validated, except: [:dash_action]

  def is_validated_action # the method that causes the redirect
  end 

  def dash_action # action of dash_path url
  end

  def already_validated
    if session[:uid] == user.id
        redirect_to dash_path
    end
  end
end
```

If you want some validation `before` the hypothetical `dash_action` then create a new method for it. Be sure that you don't have circular references or it will be pretty difficult to debug on the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can just tell Rails to skip the before filter in the controller that handles the `dash_path`:

```
# in the controller
skip_before_action :already_validated
```

Read about [Filters in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

Comment: Hey! I'm trying to redirect them back to the sign in path id they attempt to access the dash_path. So I need that controller to have that before_action filter?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand. What redirects do you have in place in the different controllers? More than the one you already mentioned in your question? You might want to update your question with all redirects that happen in before_actions.